# Chebyshev's inequality and CLT to approximate 1.000.000 coin tosses probability

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

*Let S be the number of heads in 1,000,000 tosses of a fair coin. Use Chebyshev’s
inequality, and the CLT to estimate the probability
that S lies between 499,500 and 500,500. Use the same two methods
to estimate the probability that S lies between 499,000 and 501,000.*

*S lies between 499,500 and 500,500*  :

Using **CLT** : $$P(499500 \leq S_{n} \leq 500500)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\approx \Phi(3) - \Phi(-3) \approx 0.6826$$

Using **Chebyshev's inequality** : $$P(|X-500000| \geq 500) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{500^2} = \frac{np(1-p)}{500^2} = 1$$

*S lies between 499,000 and 501,000* :

Using **CLT** : $$P(499000 \leq S_{n} \leq 501000)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\approx \Phi(2) - \Phi(-2) \approx 0.9544$$

Using **Chebyshev's inequality** : $$P(|X-500000| \geq 1000) \leq \frac{Var(X)}{1000^2} = \frac{np(1-p)}{1000^2} = \frac{1}{4}$$
Where am I wrong in the Chebyshev's inequality ?

Comment: You are not wrong. $0.9544 \gt 1-\frac14$, as the Chebyshev inequality requires

Comment: Where did $\Phi(3) - \Phi(-3)$ come from?

Answer (score 1):

$P(|X-500000| \geq 500) < 1$ is trivial.

The another case

\begin{align}
P(|X-500000| \geq 1000) &= P(X \geq 501000) + P(X \leq 499000)\\
&= 1 - P(499000 \leq X \leq 501000) \\
&\approx 1-0.9544=0.0456 < 1/4
\end{align}

Everything is ok, isn't it ?

Comment: So how can I bound *S lies between 499,000 and 501,000* using Chebyshev's inequality ?

Comment: I did $1-P(|X-500000| \geq 1000) = P(499000 \leq X \leq 501000)  > 1 - \frac{1}{4} = 0.75$ but how can I find the upper bound ?

Comment: @RomainB. you cant because Chebyshev inequality gives the tail of distribution, not the center.

Answer (score 1):

There are random variables with virtually all the probability distribution less than one standard deviation away from the mean, and there are random variables with all the probability distribution less than or equal to one standard deviation away from the mean; the Chebyshev inequality has to take these into account

Here $\mu=500000$ and $\sigma=500$. The cases are one and two standard deviations from the mean

So look at the directions of the Chebyshev inequalities and the trivial bounds the other side; there are also variants altering the strictness of the inequalities

$$0 \lt P(|X-\mu| \geq \sigma) \leq  1$$ $$0 \le P(|X-\mu| \geq 2\sigma) \leq   \frac14$$

and in the other direction

$$0 \lt P(|X-\mu| \leq \sigma) \leq   1$$ $$\frac34 \leq P(|X-\mu| \leq 2\sigma) \leq  1$$

Comment: Do you mean $\mu =  500000$?

Comment: @Larry - indeed I did - so edited - thank you